# HP server converted from physical to virtual has no network devices and mouse won't captured after every reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I just converted HP Proliant DL380 G7 Windows Server R2 Standard using Disk2Vhd utility. Removed a few HP based things, assigned static IP addresses and then rebooted.

When rebooted, there were no network adapters and no mouse capture. Somehow I've installed the network adapter and captured the mouse. Then rebooted again.

After every reboot the network adapter & related devices have lost. There is no Hyper-V Signal and other devices, either. I could discover "new" network device at Device Manager and I can see the lost one in hidden devices list. It seems like unplugged.

I've tried to remove every single device under System Devices and rebooted. Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard has initialized like a charm and an IP address has been assigned in a blink. Windows has discovered many devices again which I removed just before. I've booted again and viola! No mouse capture and no network adapters again.

I couldn't use Physical to Virtual Migration Wizard, it won't work.

What would be the wrong with that guest OS?

Comment: There had been a number of updates to Hyper-V 2008 R2's Integration Services, but SP1 should have the latest available. Did you try re-installing the IS on the guest? And you do have SP1 installed, don't you?

Comment: All updates installed on HP + Hyper-V Host.

Comment: I've just disabled HP based services. Now it seems OK.